# Virtual properties in SequelizeJS do not work

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have following schema in SequelizeJS:

```
var moment = require('moment');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
var Account = sequelize.define('Account', {
    suspended: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
    }
}, {
    getterMethods: {
        trialDaysLeft: function() {
            return 5;
        }
    },
         tableName: 'accounts'
});
    return Account;
};
```

I want to get trialDaysLeft when I call account.trialDaysLeft property.

I am getting

```
TypeError: Property 'trialDaysLeft' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name might not be the most intuitive but what `getterMethods` actually does is generate properties with getter methods on the instance objects.

So in this instance you would need to call `instance.trialDaysLeft` and not `instance.trialDaysLeft()` (which i'm guessing is what you're doing).